# React Native Linking to web page and push back button

Tags: react-native

I built a react-native app and if user clicks a link then app opens a default web browser and go to the link.

```
Linking.openURL(notification.link);
```

If user push back button from the android or ios devices, is there any way we can detect the back move?

Answer (score 1):

*You can add a listener for the same in react native.*

There are total 4 listners for the same.

1. **willFocus** - the screen will focus
2. **didFocus** - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
3. **willBlur** - the screen will be unfocused
4. **didBlur** - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

Try the below code

```
componentWillMount(){
    const didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      payload => {
        console.warn('didFocus ', payload);
        # just write your code/call a method here which you want to execute when the app comes from background
      }
    );
}
```

Dont forget to remove it when it is done.

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    didFocusSubscription.remove();
}
```

More you can read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle). Thanks :)