# re Render a life-cycle in React Native after the user change screen between mobile browser and page

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a Life cycle or a method in React, specifically in React native that calls a component render after the user change screen between a mobile browser and an open screen?

for example I want to get the wallet amount once the user went to the browser payment gateway and do a successful transaction. the browser page calls the package name of the app and the app opens in the same wallet screen I have. since I am already in the page the page wont get re rendered (componentDidMount) and i cant call the api in (ComponentDidUpdate) is state manger like context or redux the only solution?

Comment: this will help you ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225512/react-native-linking-to-web-page-and-push-back-button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Linking to web page and push back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225512/react-native-linking-to-web-page-and-push-back-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `AppState` to check if your app resumed

```
import { AppState, AppStateStatus } from 'react-native';
...

componentDidMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.onAppStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.onAppStateChange);
}

onAppStateChange(state) {
  if (state === 'active') {
    // Add code to check your wallet here
  }
}
```